# Revisiting the top of the tagstack

Tags: vim, tags

I'm using tags in Vim, with tagstack enabled.

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to select a tag, Vim gives me three possibilities, I choose the second.

I then return to the original context with `:pop`.

I'd then like to select the same tag again, but the place I jumped to last time is not on the tagstack, because I only jumped to it, not from it. I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> and select the second of three again, but I'd like the facility to simply go where I went before.

Is this possible?

Comment: BTW, Ctrl-t does the same thing as :pop does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> to jump to the last place you visited. It is not exactly what you described but effectively you reach the line you want faster.

Also, you can hit <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> if you want to visit the second option, which seems to skip the choosing part.

Otherwise, it doesn't seem to be possible as you actually lose the information about the tag when you `:pop`.